# Does iAd support my own advertisers?

Tags: ios, iad

I have clients that want to pay for advertising within my app. If I implement iAd ads, will they be able to purchase space in my app directly?

What's the best route for including ads in an iOS app if you already have access to the people who want to purchase ad space? Is it iAd or something else?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. It's so far off topic that none of the usual "off topic" reasons cover it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob (http://www.admob.com) offer a really easy way to get ads into your apps including ads you source yourself using the House Ads feature.

All you need is a Google account. The integration is also very easy.

To allow for multiple ad-networks within your app, have a look at AdWhirl as well. https://www.adwhirl.com/